# chkrootkit question. suspect files

Tags: chkrootkit

I recently had a spear fishing attempt on my Linux Ubuntu 18.04  I changed passwords and ran Chkrootkit and Clamscan

my chkrootkit scan came up with the following:

```
suspicious files and directories were found:  
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit /usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo /lib/modules/4.15.0-115-generic/vdso/.build-id /lib/modules/4.15.0-112-generic/vdso/.build-id
/usr/lib/debug/.build-id /lib/modules/4.15.0-115-generic/vdso/.build-id /lib/modules/4.15.0-112-generic/vdso/.build-id
```

Is there a way to test if these are false positives?  I update my software regularly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are all hidden files, and hidden files are labelled as suspicious. Definitely not false positives, but probably nothing to worry about.

Comment: `dpkg -S filename` will show the package (if any) that provides the file. Other tools to apply to each file: `ls -l`, `file`, `less`. `chkrootkit` is an automated tool (a bunch of scripts), and is set to announce things that look strange. The `.build-id` files are strange, in that they are not visible to `ls` without the `-a` or `-A` options. They look to me like leftovers from a software build, but that could be camouflage.